# Is there any way in calabash- android to run a single step in a scenario for multiple times

Tags: calabash-android

I want to run a single step in the my scenarios for multiple times. My scenario consists of connect and disconnect steps.

I have used the while loop to do a work around for it,but was helpless, as the test fails with 'Ambiguous match of "I tap on disconnect button":'. This may be reason as the test executes the same line "I tap on disconnect button" or "I tap on connect" multiple,which Gerkhin may not support as the language is repeating while the loop is running.
Here are the steps:

```
Then I select the item from the list
Then I tap on disconnect button
Then I tap on connect to reconnect
```

I want second two steps to be executes 10 times when the run the scenarios.

Can someone help on this.

Answer (score 0):

You can make it like this

Then I restart connection

step def:

```
  $i = 0 
  $num = 10
   while $i < $num  do
      #YOUR CODE HERE
      #DISCONNECT
      sleep(3)
      #CONNECT
      puts("Inside the loop i = #$i" )
      $i +=1
   end
```

It should work if you use only one element of UI and you dont change it, on the other hand to help you in future if you have problem with multiply different elements in calabash-android use Table calabash-android construction.

Answer (score 0):

Could you not just make the step definition

`Then I reconnect 5 times`

Step def

```
Then /^I reconnect (.*) times$/ do |repetitions|
  repetition.times do
    ... your code here
  end
end
```